# Navigate to subdirectory(windows) using wildcard character

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If suppose I need to navigate to a subfolder using wildcard character what is the command in cmd (not in powershell)

Example

My current directory is c:\Users\Test

I have a sub folder as 3(only one folder)

I want to navigate to c:\Users\Test\3\test1

> C:\Users\Test> cd .\*\test1
>
> "The system cannot find the path specified."

What is the command to navigate ?

Comment: Can I ask what the motivation is behind using a wild card rather than the full path?

Comment: Since that folder is a version no. It will always change. I dont want to modify the script again and again.

Comment: Thanks, are you looking for a particular filename within that directory? The reason I am asking is that I am not sure that it is possible to do exactly what you have asked (at least I don't know of a way), but there may well be a suitable work around depending on what you need to do once you have found the directory.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for /d /r c:\users\test %%a in (test1) do if exist "%%~a" cd "%%~a"
```